# How to fix emacs popup dialogs on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, emacs, crash

I'm out of ideas here - my emacs crashes when popup dialog is opened. The [x-popup-dialog function is probably to blame](http://osdir.com/ml/bug-gnu-emacs-gnu/2009-04/msg00688.html) but I found no workaround to this. My Emacs version is 23.1.1 . Unfortunately some functionality of emacs calls this (e.x. customize asks whether it should save the changes) which causes the crash.

Does anybody know how to fix it or disable it?

Comment: The bug is tagged `moreinfo`: http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=2877  Maybe someone could get the ball rolling again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a quick elisp bit that will completely disable the graphical dialog for you:

```
(defadvice yes-or-no-p (around prevent-dialog activate)
  "Prevent yes-or-no-p from activating a dialog"
  (let ((use-dialog-box nil))
    ad-do-it))
(defadvice y-or-n-p (around prevent-dialog-yorn activate)
  "Prevent y-or-n-p from activating a dialog"
  (let ((use-dialog-box nil))
    ad-do-it))
```

Add this to your .emacs and it'll disable the use of the graphical dialog for the two forms of yes-or-no prompts that emacs uses.

Comment: That made my day. However how to prevent other events from poping dialog box? I.e. flymake insist on popping this dialog when it encounters fatal error - which crashes emacs again.
Is there a way to do it on global level?

Comment: Actually, for flymake that was as easy as setting the custom-variable.

Comment: In addition to the above, you also need:
      (defadvice message-box (around prevent-dialog activate)
 "Prevent message-box from activating a dialog"
 (apply #'message (ad-get-args 0)))

Comment: This answer did not completely work for me, cmd-T still opens the native font chooser

Answer (score 2):

Wow. I had never noticed that, but `x-popup-dialog` seems to be a problem for me too.  At least the example dialog crashed for me.  How do you get customize to bring up a dialog?  I can't reproduce it.

In general the rule is: if you do it from the keyboard it won't use up a dialog.  e.g. use `C-x k` instead of the mouse to close a buffer and you'll get no dialog.  Another, more heavy-handed way, is to set `use-dialog-box` to `nil` (though that doesn't stop `x-popup-dialog` from working if called directly so it may not fix the problem).  To fix that you would probably have to advise `x-popup-dialog`, reimplement it using for example `completing-read` and never call `ad-do-it`.  Or you could fix the bug.  I'm not sure which would be easier :-)

Comment: Customize asks whether I want to save all changes for the buffer when hitting "Save for futher sessions". I thought in carbon-emacs it uses mini-buffer. :/
I will try setting use-dialog to nil and see whether it helps. But this will happen when I get home. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: custom pops up a dialog if you mouse click a button, and uses the minibuffer if you hit enter on the button

Comment: The main problem for me is things like "cmd-T" for when I thought my browser was focused

Comment: @DustinGetz, that's a completely different problem underneath.  You can fix that by unbinding the particular key, e.g. `(global-set-key "\M-t" nil)`